# format '%s' expects argument of type '*char' but argument 2 has type 'int'

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

When I try to compile my program I get the warning message in the title and when I run it after scanning the names and scores it just stops. I encountered this problem a lot of times while practicing working with strings, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct students {
    char name[20];
    int score[20];
} student;
int main() {
int i, n;
    printf("Number of students:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Name of the student:\n");
        scanf("%s", &student.name[i]);
        printf("Score of the student:\n");
        scanf("%d", &student.score[i]);
    }
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(student.score[i] >= 15) {
        printf("%s passed the exam\n", student.name[i]); }
    else {
        printf("%s failed the exam\n", student.name[i]);
    }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what line the error is thrown at? Also what happens if you remove the `&` from the `scanf`'s?

Comment: One *char* is a single character. A letter, digit or so. You've got *20* characters worth of space for names of 20 students.

Comment: Make a `struct student` in singular with *one name* composed of multiple characters, and one score. Then make an *array of student**s***.

Comment: line 19 and 21.

Comment: @scylla0120 - to address a specific comment, you can enter the "@" followed by the users moniker.  eg: `@B. Cratty` in the comment box and it will flag that user that you have responded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues:

```
printf("%s passed the exam\n", student.name[i]);
```

`student.name[i]` is a `char` but the `%s` format specifier wants a pointer to `char`.

But the actual problem is that your declaration of students is not what you need. Following structure declares one student whose name can be up to 19 characters long and having 20 scores.

```
struct students {
    char name[20];
    int score[20];
} student;
```

But you need 20 (or more?) students each of them having one score:

```
struct student {
  char name[50];    // name up to 49 characters
  int score;        // score
} student;

struct student students[20];  // array of 20 students
```

Il leave the implementation of the code to the reader as an exercise.
You need to get familiar with following concepts:

- arrays
- structs
- strings
- basics of `scanf` and `printf`

All these topics are covered in your C text book.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have quite a few issue.
1) student should be array ( or dynamically memory allocated).
2) scanf of string needs to be done as

`scanf("%s", student[i].name)`

Or

`scanf("%s", &student[i].name[0])`

3) Still you would have issue if string length crosses 20 byte (include nul character).

Answer (score 0):

```
char name[20];
```

sets aside space for a *single* 20-character string, so `students.name[i]` refers to a single character (which gets promoted to type `int` in the `scanf` call).

To define an array of *strings*, you need a 2D array of `char`, like

```
char name[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
```

and you read it as

```
scanf( “%s”, student.name[i] ); // no & operator here
```

Array expressions “decay” to pointer expression under most circumstances, so you don’t need the `&` operator here.

Alternately, you can declare an array of pointers to `char`, like

```
char *name[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS];
```

and then allocate memory for each string as you read it:

```
char buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
...
scanf( “%s”, buffer );
student.name[i] = malloc( strlen( buffer ) + 1 );
if ( student.name[i] )
  strcpy( student.name[i], buffer );
```

You just need to remember to `free` each `student.name[i]` when you’re finished.

Answer (score 0):

The student name is a singular array of char and needs to be an array of character arrays.

```
struct students {
    char name[20][40];
    int score[20];
} student;
```

I arbitrarily assumed 40 characters per name was sufficient.

The scanf for the name needs to be changed from:

```
scanf("%s", &student.name[i]);
```

To:

```
scanf("%s", student.name[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", &student.name[i]);` You're addressing a single `char` from the string you declared. I assume you would want an individual object for every student. To do this my advice would be to define your `struct` like this:

```
typedef struct students {
    char name[20];
    int score;
}Student;
```

With this you have defined a new data type called `Student`. Each object of the type `Student` has a string called `name` and an `int` resembling the score.

After you've created this model, you can treat it as just another variable type, e.g. the following is totally valid:

```
Student student1, student2;
```

Alternatively, you could create an array of `Student`s: `Student group[20]` and then have a loop fill it with data:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        puts("Name of the student: ");
        fgets(group[i].name, 20, stdin);
        puts("Score of the student: ");
        scanf("%d", &group[i].score);
}
```

The deal is per iteration to refer to an individual object of the array of students. 
Also, I would strongly recommend to use `fgets()` or at least `gets_s()` for inputting strings. `scanf()` has multiple problems, some of which are that it stops input if it encounters a space, tab or a newline and most importantly it doesn't check for array bounds. Consider using a safer variant, just keep in mind that `fgets()` appends a `'\n'` before the terminating null.

Comment: About your very last sentence: If a `newline` character is present, `fgets` will _retain_ it, but it does not _append_ a `newline` character otherwise.  An ASCII NUL byte is the only thing `fgets` will append to the end of the string it reads.